How to completely drop a mongodb databased in Laravel using MongoDB/Client?
I am creating a mongodb database using Mongo Client in Laravel. This is my code;
use MongoDB\Client as MongoClient;

$databaseName     = 'little_buds';
$collectionName   = 'test'; 

$client           = new MongoClient();       // Connect to MongoDB server                        
$database         = $client->$databaseName;  // Dynamically create a database                        
$database->$collectionName->insertOne(array('key' => 'value'));  // Insert a document into the collection

Now, I want to drop the database 'little_buds'. How can I do it using Mongo Client in Laravel?
PS- I am using Laravel 9.

Does this answer your question? How to perform drop() using MongoDB drivers for php 7?
